# How to statically analyse that a file is fit for importing?

Tags: node.js

I have CLI program that can be executed with a list of files that describe instructions, e.g.

```
node ./my-program.js ./instruction-1.js ./instruction-2.js ./instruction-3.js
```

This is how I am importing and validating that the target file is an instruction file:

```
const requireInstruction = (instructionFilePath) => {
    const instruction = require(instructionFilePath)

    if (!instruction.getInstruction) {
        throw new Error('Not instruction file.');
    }

    return instruction;
};
```

The problem with this approach is that it will execute the file executes regardless of whether it matches the expected signature, i.e. if file contains a side action such as connecting to the database:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

mysql.createConnection(..);

module.exports = mysql;
```

`Not instruction file.` will fire, I will ignore the file, but the side-action will remain in the background.

How to safely validate target file signature?

Worst case scenario, is there a conventional way to completely sandbox the require logic and kill the process if file is determined to be unsafe?

Answer (score 1):

> Worst case scenario, is there a conventional way to completely sandbox the require logic and kill the process if file is determined to be unsafe?

Move the check logic into a specific js file. Make it `process.exit(0)` when everything is fine, `process.exit(1)` when it s wrong.

In your current program, instead of loading the file via require, use `child_process.exec` to invoke your new file, giving it the required parameter to know which file to test.

In your updated program, bind the close event to know if the return code was `0` or `1`.

If you need more information than `0` or `1`, into the new js file which will load the instruction, print some JSON.stringified data to `stdout` (console.log), and retrieve then JSON.parse it in the callback of call to `child_process.exec`.

Alternatively, have you looked into AST processing ?
http://jointjs.com/demos/javascript-ast

It could help you to identify piece of code which are not embedded within an exported function.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I discussed this question with the author on IRC. There may be some context in my answer that isn't in the original question.)

Given that your scenario is purely about preventing against *accidental* inclusion of non-instruction files, rather than about preventing malicious behaviour, static analysis using something like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) will probably be sufficient.

One approach would be to require that every instruction file exports some kind of object with a `name` property, containing the name of the instruction file. As there's not really anything to put in there besides a string literal, you can be *fairly* certain that if you can't locate a `name` property through static analysis, the file is not an instruction file - even in a language like JavaScript that isn't fully statically analyzable.

---

For any readers of this thread that are trying to protect from *malicious* actors, rather than accidents - for example, when accepting untrusted code from users: you **cannot** sandbox or 'validate' JavaScript with Node.js alone (not with the `vm` module either), and the above solution **will not work for you**. You will need system-level containerization or virtualization to run this kind of code safely. There are no other options.